# Has JK Rowling said anything further about the Knights of Walpurgis?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

JK Rowling once mentioned in a Harry Potter special edition of Newsnight that the Death Eaters were originally called the Knights of Walpurgis.

> **Jeremy Paxman:** And these scraps of paper which you've filed elegantly in a carrier bag, they're plot ideas or...
>   **JK Rowling:** Well some of them are totally redundant now because its been written and I keep them out of sentimentality's sake, I suppose. But some of it has backstory in it like this - in here is the history of the Death Eaters and I don't know that I'll ever actually need it - but at some point - which were once called something different - they were called the Knights of Walpurgis. I don't know if I'll need it. But I like knowing it. I like to keep that sort of stuff on hand.
>   <sub>*([Newsround; Full Transcipt of JK's OOTP Interview](http://news.bbc.co.uk/cbbcnews/hi/uk/newsid_3004000/3004878.stm))*.</sub>

(18:11)

Now I'm aware of the mythology and the traditions around [Walpurgis Night](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walpurgis_Night). I'm interested in whether JK Rowling herself has passed further comment on this in any way - whether through a Pottermore article or another interview. Has she?

Comment: Updated my answer a bit. Still nothing though. (Unless they ever decide to release an HD copy of that documentary.)

Comment: @ibid Thanks for the extra work. Maybe they'll bring out a cinematic version one day where the text will be readable.

Comment: I know that a higher quality copy *exists* (based on [this tweet](https://twitter.com/lizo_mzimba/status/545196842427101186)) from the producer. I don't think it was ever released though.

Comment: Knights of Walpurgis sounds like some fraternal order with chapters in every small town. Their annual Midnight Pancake Breakfast is on April 30/May 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### She has not said anything futher

As usual it is hard to prove a negative, but a ctrl+f through all of her written works, accio-quote, and tweets do not turn up anything else.

Additionally, all the main secondary sources (e.g. wikia, lexicon, <strike>buzzfeed</strike>pottermore) do not show any other sources.

It seems that the 2003 CBBC interview is the only place where the term was mentioned.

**Though if you have really good eyes you may be able to glean something from this image:**

> [image]
>
> This is an old notebook in which I worked out, and again I don't want you to come too close on this, "that!" (*quickly flashes notebook at camera*)  is the history of the death-eaters.
>
> <sub>"[Harry Potter & Me](https://youtu.be/SrJiAG8GmnQ?t=568)" - BBC, 28 December 2001</sub>

Comment: I think _you_ of all people can say this without needing to prove it. +1